# Can I use tuple as a key in mapping?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I want to do this

```
 struct A
    {
        uint x;
        string str;
    }
 mapping ((uint,bytes32,uint)=> structA);
```

Can use tuple as a key in mapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, only elementary types can be used as keys, see the documentation: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.8/types.html#mapping-types

You can however convert the tuple to a `bytes32` type using the `keccak256` hash function and use that value safely as the key, like this:

`keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a, b, c))`

where `a, b, c` would be the values of your tuple.